# Codeigniter add message ( private message ) into database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and I would like to ask for some help.

**What I am trying to accomplish**: Send a message to a user, like a private message.

**What I have so far**:

**View**:

```
 <?php echo form_open('/admin/enquire/add_message/'.$enquire->id); ?>

                        <div class="form-group form-group-standard">
                          <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <?php echo form_error('message'); ?><br />
          <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'message', 'name' => 'message')); ?><br />

                            <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
         CKEDITOR.replace( 'message', {
                  toolbar: 'Basic',
                  uiColor: '#ffffff',
                  height: '120px'
                  });
          });


       </script>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-group-standard">
                          <div class="col-lg-12">
                           <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?><br/>
```

**Controller**:

```
 public function add_message()
{
     $thread_id = $this->uri->segment(4);


     $data = array(
                    'thread_id' => $this->uri->segment(4),
                    'sender_id' =>  $this->session->userdata('id'),
                    'name_surname' => $this->session->userdata('name_surname'),
                    'date' => NOW(),
                    'message' => $this->input->post('message'),
                    'readed' => '0');

$this->insert_message->form_insert($data);

redirect('admin/enquire/view/'.$enquire->id);
}
```

**Model**:

```
class insert_model extends MY_Model{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();

}
function form_insert($data){
// Inserting in Table(students) of Database(college)
$this->db->insert('message_replies', $data);
}
}
```

**DB:**

`thread_id           int(11) NOT NULL,
 id                  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sender_id          int(11) NOT NULL,
  recepient_id       int(11) NOT NULL,
  name_surname       varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  date               datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  message            text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  readed             binary(1) DEFAULT '0',`

**URL:**

```
index.php/admin/enquire/view/19
```

or

```
index.php/admin/enquire/add_message/19
```

after submit.

What I am trying to do is to insert the message from the textfield into the database ( the table name is `message_replies`).

When I hit the submit button I get nothing. It shows white screen.
Nothing is imported in the database either.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: I dnt think the model name would be the problem...

Comment: If you get a white screen, that usually means there's an error but error reporting is turned off. You can add these lines to the top of your controller method to ensure that errors will be shown: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Thank you Matt! The problem was with the " 'date' => NOW(), " in the controller. It worked with  'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). It creates a record in the DB now, but it does not insert the message. Maybe, there's smthing wrong with the message text field...

Comment: If you want to see what data is being used for the query, you could do `var_dump($data);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to load the model in your controller as follow:-

```
$this->load->model('insert_model');
```

Now you can call your model methods using an object with the same name as your class as follow:

```
$this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
```

Also add `recepient_id` in your data array.
So now your controller function my look like this:

```
    public function add_message()
    {
        $this->load->model('insert_model');     
        $thread_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $data = array(
                    'thread_id' => $this->uri->segment(4),
                    'sender_id' =>  $this->session->userdata('id'),
                    'name_surname' => $this->session->userdata('name_surname'),
                    'date' => NOW(),
                    'message' => $this->input->post('message'),
                    'readed' => '0');

          $this->insert_model->form_insert($data);

          redirect('admin/enquire/view/'.$enquire->id);
}
```

Don't forget your model should extend the CI's parent model like:

```
class Insert_model extends CI_Model
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but unfortunately the result is the same. White screen and no data inserted into the database.

Comment: 'recepient_id' is missing in your data array. you should provide a recepient_id also.